# How do I change textarea value and put cusor at the beginnig?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function testfn () {
            $('.texta').html('stuff');

            if ($('.texta')[0].createTextRange) {
                var part = $('.texta')[0].createTextRange();
                part.move("character", 0);
                part.select();
            } else if ($('.texta')[0].setSelectionRange) {
                $('.texta')[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
            }
            $('.texta').focus();

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea class="texta"></textarea>
<button onclick="testfn();">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

After the button is pressed, textarea value is changing and it's focused. But the cursor is at the end of the text.
How do I move it to the beginning of this textarea after its value has been changed?

**UPD:** @San's approach works well in Chrome, I still need a solution for FF

**UPD2:** The above code is working now (one should use `$('.texta')[0]` instead of `$('.texta')`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function testfn () {
            $('.texta').html('stuff');

           if ($('.texta').createTextRange) {
            var part = $('.texta').createTextRange();
            part.move("character", 0);
            part.select();
            }else if ($('.texta').setSelectionRange){
            $('.texta').setSelectionRange(0, 0);}
            $('.texta').focus();

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think your way is the best, but it works in Chrome(-ium), but not FF. Any ideas? :)

Comment: can you give whats the progress? is the text injected into field? and focusing is not done in FF? or nothing happened?

Comment: See my edit: I've changed `$('.texta')` to `$('.texta')[0]` in those functions, now works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve as below

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#Test").click(function(){

        $('.texta').focus();
            $('.texta').val('stuff');
        $('.texta').selectRange(0,0);
    });
});

$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="texta"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="Test" onClick="testfn();" value="test"></input>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rVgrq/)

Comment: Yes, Tushar Gupta is few second faster.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/mE6Fg/)

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="texta"></textarea>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

**js**

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    var text = $('.texta');
    text.focus().val('stuff').selectRange(0,0);
});
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    if(!end) end = start; 
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You were slightly faster ;)